# Travel Photography 3.5V 3,6-4,8A LED Lamp powered by power bank

Tags: power-supply, led, low-power, lighting, lamp

I travel a lot for my work as a photographer. For this I'm building a custom full spectrum lamp.

I have no issue running my build with a normal adjustable power supply from my studio.
To be able to adjust the brightness, I build the lamp with a switch to turn on additional led's. Which is why my amp changes from 3,6-4,8A.
Also there is a cooling fan which is meant to be for 5V but it works at 3,5V just fine.

However when traveling I use power banks for everything. So I would have liked to run my lamps off them as well.

**Here is where I'm stuck:**
I need a rather small and efficient way of transforming 5V into the desired 3.5V (led's work form 3,1 - 3,7V according to the manufacturer).
This has to work with power banks, which usually automatically adjust their output voltage to the device.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is a power bank?

Comment: @MadHatter Common name for a portable rechargeable battery pack with USB ports for charging things with.

Comment: I've never seen a power bank that adjusts its output voltage to the device, unless you're talking about USB-PD or QC, both of which require the device to do special things to request more than 5V. And both of which are rather rare in power banks, last I checked. Ignore the QC/PD stuff and just treat it as a constant 5V power source, because that's what it is unless you have circuitry specifically designed to ask it for more.

Comment: That amount of power will be hard to get out of a power bank, if your talking about the typical ones used for phones etc.

Comment: @Hearth Most better modern power banks seem to automatically adjust their voltage between 5 and 9/12V. I assume this is done for compatibility reasons. Now I dont know how exactly they do this internally so I can't really say if it will be a problem.
I will just try treating it as 5V and see how it behaves if I cant get anymore info on it.

Comment: @MadHatter Getting the power out is not my issue. Only issue is how to keep my power bank from automatically stepping up my voltage. And then to be able to step down the 5V to 3.5V in a way that is as efficient and small as possible.

Comment: Budget is not a problem. I work as a professional and can spend 1k per lamp if I have to. It has to work and be small and light. And I need it yesterday tbh... I'm building this cause I can't get the special led's I want to use in any commercial build. Neither can I get a commercial build in a small light scale powered by power banks.

Comment: @PogchampLetsgodude This is either USB-PD or QC, and is never done without the explicit permission of the device drawing power. If you don't add special circuitry specifically to negotiate the higher voltage, you will get 5V out. If you get any voltage other than 5V without specifically negotiating it, the power bank is broken and should be replaced.